# Hamiltonian path in $\{0,1\}^n$ with rotations and bit-flip in position 0

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, hamiltonian-graphs

We consider any non-negative integer as an ordinal, that is $0=\emptyset$ and $n=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$ for every positive integer. Let $\{0,1\}^n$ denote the set of $\{0,1\}$-vectors of length $n$.

Define the *left-rotation* $\ell_n:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ in the following way: For $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ let $$\big(\ell_n(x)\big)_k = x_{k+1} \text{ for } k\in n-1\text{ and } \big(\ell_n(x)\big)_{n-1} = x_0.$$ It is easy to see that $\ell_n: \{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ is a bijection for every positive integer $n$; the *right-rotation* $r_n :\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ is the inverse of $\ell_n$.

Moreover the *bit-flip at position 0*, $b_n: \{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ is defined by: For $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ let $$\big(b_n(x)\big)_0 = 1-x_0\text{ and } \big(b_n(x)\big)_k = x_k\text{ for all }k\in n\setminus\{0\}.$$

Define an edge set $E_n$ on $\{0,1\}^n$ in the following way:
$$E_n = \big\{\{x,y\}: x\neq y \in \{0,1\}^n \text{ and }\big(y = \ell_n(x) \text{ or } y = r_n(x) \text{ or }y = b_n(x)\big)\big\}.$$

It is easy to see that the graph $(\{0,1\}^n, E_n)$ is connected.

**Question.** Given an integer $n>1$, does $(\{0,1\}^n, E_n)$ have a Hamiltonian path? Or even a Hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: It doesn't have a Hamiltonian cycle, because $0^n$ and $1^n$ each shift to themselves and so only have one edge.

Comment: Using computer calculations, I verified that $E_n$ has a Hamiltonian path whenever $n\leq 6$.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks to both of your comments. Using your computer calculations, @JosephVanName, did an interesting pattern emerge of how the Hamiltonian path was generated, or does it look "random-like"?

Comment: I could not see any interesting discernable patterns from the calculations.